# Stackoverflow error when compiling scala with gradle 7.6

Tags: scala, gradle, sbt, zinc

I have a scala project that is using Scala 2.12.17. I currently am not able to update the Scala version for various reasons. I am compiling it with Gradle. I want to update Gradle from version 6.8.3 to 7.6, however when doing so I get a stackoverflow error. I found [this](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6838) and [this](https://github.com/sbt/zinc/issues/1010) issue in the sbt/zinc compiler about an incompatibility between sbt 1.5.8 and Scala 2.12.4, however Gradle 7.6 defaults to sbt/zinc 1.6.1, and I am using Scala 2.12.17, which from what I can tell from those Github issues should work. If I set the Zinc version to 1.5.7 this works, but I would rather use an up to date version of Zinc.

Any leads?

Comment: this is also obviously due to some issue in the code, because i have another project that has the same exact specs and it compiles just fine... I wonder what about the way the code is structured leads to this issue